# show ambient occlusion in render output

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have discovered Ambient Occlusion and I really dig the effect it has on my model in Object mode / solid view. However when I change to Render view I don't see the effect. Can I get it in the render?

UPDATE: got part of the way but still not seeing the result in the render. New screenshots below. 
/update

Generally speaking is there a way / are there ways to have the render come out more like the 3D View?

Blender 2.79b, Cycles render.

[image: 3d view with AO]
[image: render view no AO showing]
[image: settings]

[image: node editor]
[image: panel1]
[image: panel2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option in that menu is for the viewport only. To achieve the same effect in a cycles render you must either enable the setting in the world tab of the [properties](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/blender_render/world/ambient_occlusion.html) menu.

The best way to do this would be to enable an AO pass, which should be enabled by default.
[image]

You can then composite the AO pass with your image and control the effect after you've rendered. This is usually the node setup I use to control AO when compositing. 
[image]

Comment: Ah okay I need to learn the node editor then. Thanks !

Comment: hello @aglet, I got part of the way but not seeing a result in my render. Also I can't find 'Multiply' as an element option in my shift-A options in node editor. Anything missing? I'll update the post above with some new photos.

Comment: I should also probably add, I'm using the render preview window to look. Does an AO effect show in the render preview, or do you have to run a full render pass?

Comment: Multiply is an option under the 'Mix' node. Node setups do not effect the render preview, though the AO option in the World properties shows up in the render preview. That option is very similar but I'd recommend either going with one or the other as it's basically doing the same thing (multiplying or adding the AO with the render).